# Cortex-M3 realtime interrupt vector remap

Tags: c, gcc, interrupt, cortex-m, linker-scripts

I use GCC 4.9 (arm-none-eabi) with STM32 and want to place an interrupt table into an array in order to change interrup handler adresses when it's needed in my code.
I read existing manuals and articles and did the following:

I have to align the array, so I changed the linker script to add custom section in RAM and place it to 0x20001000 in order to automatically align it

```
 .vectorsSection 0x20001000 :
  {    
    KEEP(*(.vectorsSection))       
  } >RAM
```

Declare array to place IVT into, I declared it as extern in the header, and in .cc:

```
volatile word __attribute__((section (".vectorsSection"))) _vectors_[64] = {0};
```

Check that array is at the correct address:

```
arm-none-eabi-nm program.elf | grep _vectors_
20001000 d _ZL9_vectors_
```

Now it comes to reallocate the table to RAM. I wrote this function

```
void (*new_code_entry)(void);
.......
static void remap_vector_table (void)
{
  //VTOR is 0 on startup, so we change VTOR only once
  if(SCB->VTOR)
    return;
  new_code_entry = (void (*)(void))((word)&_vectors_ + sizeof(word) + 1);//Skip SP and jump to Reset
  memcpy((void*)_vectors_, (void*)SCB->VTOR, sizeof _vectors_);
  SCB->VTOR = 0x1FFFFF80ul & (word)(&_vectors_); //Set VTOR offset
  __DSB(); //Complete all memory requests
  new_code_entry(); //Jump to new code
}
```

I created enum from startup code in order to easy access the array.
After the final jump the code start from beginning and VTOR is 4096.
Array contain correct addresses in the same order as in the startup code.
But when it comes to

```
__enable_irq();
__ISB();
```

It hangs on the first exception, to be more specific this is the callstack

```
5 <symbol is not available> 0x697b617a   
4 <signal handler called>() 0xfffffff9   
3 <symbol is not available> 0x200011f8  
2 remap_vector_table() main.cc:31 0x08000cd4
1 main() main.cc:46 0x08000d32 

200011f4:  tickcounter+0   movs r0, r0
200011f6:  tickcounter+2   movs r0, r0
200011f8:  ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xf0d3e321
```

tickcounter is from SysTick_Handler that is surelly was called first.
May be I should do something with stack pointer?
I have no clue what is wrong here.

Comment: I have never changed an interrupt vector "when needed". I dispatch it within the interrupt, as required.

Comment: The reason is I need to change handlers from time to time. For example there are three UART1 interrupt handlers and I need to switch between them.

Comment: That's probably the result of poor code design.

Comment: Maybe, but VTOR register exists and I just want to know how to handle it in the right way when the table is in RAM

Comment: The table is always in RAM.

Comment: Sorry, I meant reallocated in RAM

Comment: I can't follow your many-bracketed code (you shouldn't need to obfuscate by casting `void*` for `memcpy`), but I notice the function `remap_vector_table()` takes no argument. Why not prepare several interrupt vector tables in advance, then call the function with an argument to tell which table to select?

Comment: so some assembly is required of course, the cortex-m, was designed so you didnt have to use as much, but for something like this either you are generating instructions and placing them in ram or just do a little assembly.  have the flash point to ram addresses for these interrupts in question (not reset of course).  the ram locations do something like load a pc relative address then branch to it then at any time you can change the address for that vector.

Comment: the alternative is to not setup ram with assembly but instead have code generate and place then instructions at runtime.  and then the same result, you can just change an address at any time to change the handler.

Comment: dwelch, would you describe the root cause as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is quite simple:

1. According to manual bit 29 is shows the base offset: RAM or FLASH.

   SCB->VTOR |= 1 << SCB_VTOR_TBLBASE_Pos;

This fixed the issue

2. There is no need in reset after changing the table - it clears my array